# KeystoneJS Variable Related Posts

Tags: node.js, keystonejs

I have a schema for `Place` and that place has a type which can have three values `region, country, city`. Each of them types have a separate Schema with a load of relevant data.

My question is; is there a way that I can connect the place to it's correct object within the schemas? I know I can just do a City.find({ ... }) to get the object data.

I did add the code below but it's not editable from the Place form in the admin section. Is it possible to do this?

```
Place.schema.virtual('data').get(function() {

    if (this.type == 'country') {
        var c = Country.findOne({ parent: this });
        if (c) {
            return c;
        }
    }

    if (this.type == 'city') {
        var c = City.findOne({ parent: this });
        if (c) {
            return c;
        }
    }

});
```

I need the place object with the name and then data for each type stored in different schemas. Can keystone handle this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create relationships between collections:

1. In your Place model (Place.js), add a field for each linked collection

   Place.add({
   title: { type: String, required: true },
   region:{ type: Types.**Relationship**, ref: 'Region' },
   country:{ type: Types.**Relationship**, ref: 'Country' },
   city:{ type: Types.**Relationship**, ref: 'City' },
   });
2. Create a model for each linked collection :

   Region.add({
       name: { type: String, required: true },
       description: { type: Types.Html, wysiwyg: true, height: 400 }
   });

   Country.add({
               name: { type: String, required: true },
               description: { type: Types.Html, wysiwyg: true, height: 400 }
       });

   City.add({
           name: { type: String, required: true },
           description: { type: Types.Html, wysiwyg: true, height: 400 }
   });
3. To have a select input in the admin, you have to add in the Place definition a drilldown property (still in your model)

var Place= new keystone.List('Place', {
    map: { name: 'title' },
    drilldown: 'Region',
    drilldown: 'Country',
    drilldown: 'City'
});

4. Don't forget to add a route in keystone.js to see the admin menu item (note the plural) :

   keystone.set('nav', {
   ...
   'places': 'places',
   ....
   });